# Getting index of inserted rows from a MySQL database

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc

I'm using Java (jdbc) to interact with a MySQL database. I have table with a primary index which is AUTO INCREMENT. When I insert a row, I need to get the index it just received. How do I do that?

Comment: How can you utilize this index to search faster laster?

Comment: @David: what do you mean? A primary key is always an index and thus will always help to search faster, if you query the index. Ask a separate question if you want more explications :)

Comment: I thought that a primary key could be indexed and isn't an index in itself. I believe that it is perfectly valid (though usually not recommended) to use a varchar(60) as primary key. It would then be interesting to retrieve the index of the primary key that was just inserted and not the value itself. More specifically, it would be useful to get some sort of a position on the disk where the last record was stored so one can quickly modify it if it turns out that it should be modified (for example due to the user clicking an undo button). Hope I am not hijacking this tread now...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html#connector-j-usagenotes-last-insert-id

```
stmt.executeUpdate(
        "INSERT INTO autoIncTutorial (dataField) "
        + "values ('Can I Get the Auto Increment Field?')",
        Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

//
// Example of using Statement.getGeneratedKeys()
// to retrieve the value of an auto-increment
// value
//

int autoIncKeyFromApi = -1;

rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();

if (rs.next()) {
    autoIncKeyFromApi = rs.getInt(1);
} else {

    // throw an exception from here
}

rs.close();

rs = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to John Boker for his excellent response.

If you wish to use a **PreparedStatement**, you can still use `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`, but you have to apply the commands differently:

```
PreparedStatement ps = mysql.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO myTable (colA, colB, colC) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
     Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS );
ps.setString(1, "My text");
ps.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()););
ps.setInt(3, 5150);
ps.executeUpdate();
ResultSet results = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
results.next(); // Assume just one auto-generated key; otherwise, use a while loop here
System.out.println(results.getInt(1)); // there should only be 1 column in your results: the value of the auto-generated key
```

1. Add the `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` param in the `prepareStatement()`
   function.
2. Get results not from `statement.executeUpdate()` but from
   `statement.getGeneratedKeys()`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using Spring JDBC it would look like:

```
 Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 map.put("column1", "test");
 map.put("column2", Boolean.TRUE);

 SimpleJdbcInsert insert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(template).withTableName("table").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
 int id = insert.executeAndReturnKey(map).intValue();
```